# REACT JS: Dynamically convert part of paragraph into an anchor tag and on click of that anchor tag do an API call before doing a redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React JSX I want to convert a part of the text into an anchor tag dynamically. Also on click of the anchor tag, I want to do some API call before redirecting it to the requested page. But I am failing to achieve this. Can anyone have a look and let me know where am I going wrong?

I have recreated the issue on code sandbox: here is the URL: [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-click-event-on-anchor-in-template-literal-v9vhc?file=/src/App.js)

Relevant code from sandbox:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let bodyTextProp =
    "This text will have a LINK which will be clicked and it will perform API call before redirect";
  let start = 22;
  let end = 26;
  let anchorText = bodyTextProp.substring(start, end);
  let anchor = `<a 
                    href="www.test.com" 
                    onClick={${(e) => handleClick(e)}}
                  >
                    ${anchorText}
                  </a>`;

  bodyTextProp = bodyTextProp.replace(anchorText, anchor);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("The link was clicked.");
  };

  const handleClick2 = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("The link was clicked.");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: bodyTextProp }} />
      <a href="www.google.com" onClick={(e) => handleClick2(e)}>
        Test Link
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It difficult to understand what you mean,can you try to be more precise about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sure I have a string variable in which I have to dynamically convert 'LINK' text into an anchor link. But I want to call an API before doing a normal page redirect. What I am doing:
1. Extracting the text
2. Enclosing the text in ANCHOR tag 
3. Attaching an onClick event to do preventDefault and do my stuff

But when I am clicking on the link it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is variable scope. While it is entirely possible to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as you are doing, the `onClick` event isn't going to work the same way. It's going to expect `handleClick` to be a GLOBAL function, not a function scoped to the React component. That's because React doesn't know anything about the "dangerous" html.

Normally React is using things like `document.createElement` and `addEventListener` to construct the DOM and add events. And since it's using `addEventListener`, it can use the local function. But `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` bypasses all of that and just gives React a string to insert directly into the DOM. It doesn't know or care if there's an event listener, and doesn't try to parse it out or anything. Not really a good scenario at all.

The best solution would be to refactor your code so you don't need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

*Edit: since you say that you need to do multiple replacements and simply splitting the string won't suffice, I've modified the code to use a [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

When used with a RegExp with a capturing group, you can keep the delimiter in the array, and can then look for those delimiters later in your map statement. If there is a match, you add an a

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let bodyTextProp =
    "This text will have a LINK which will be clicked and it will perform API call before redirect";
  let rx = /(\bLINK\b)/;
  let array = bodyTextProp.split(rx);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log("The link was clicked.");
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleClick2 = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("The link was clicked.");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>
        {array.map((x) => {
          if (rx.test(x))
            return (
              <a href="www.test.com" onClick={handleClick}>
                {x}
              </a>
            );
          else return x;
        })}
      </h3>
      <a href="www.google.com" onClick={(e) => handleClick2(e)}>
        Test Link
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks David for answering and adding the code in the question. I got it what you are saying but there is a problem in my case the text can have multiple anchor link and doing preLink and postLink approach will not work there. That is why I wanted to do text.replace().

Comment: @RahulSahni I've edited my answer to hopefully accomplish what you want. It uses a combination of `split` and `map` instead of `replace`, which should be more React friendly.